# Ajax not showing the server answer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm making a simple chat in php, and when I send the user message ajax, it is not being showed in the page, I'm beginning to study ajax now, so I don't know what is wrong in the code, I did just like I saw to do in the w3schools

Now I'm just trying to check if the message will be showed in the page, not doing nothing really in the server, when I can fix this problem, I'll make the class for sending to database, I tried sending by post, but not working too

```
// this is the ajax in the chat.html

<script type="text/javascript">
    let send = document.querySelector('#send-mes');
    send.addEventListener('click', load);

    function load() {
        let msg = chat.msg.value;
        let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readystate==4&&this.status==200) {
                    let content = document.querySelector('#content');
                content.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
        xml.open('get', 'ajx.php?msg='+msg, true);
        xml.send();
    }
</script>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// this is the code in the server ajx.php

$ajx = $_REQUEST['msg'];
echo $ajx;
```

I want the message that is being sent by ajax to the server to appear in the #content tag (I didn't put the tag here), but nothing is happening (later I'll improve the server, now I just want to fix this), if anybody want to see all the code, you can see in my github https://github.com/CristoferPortela/chatbox.git

Comment: what error messages are in your browser dev console?  what error messages are in your php logs?

Comment: where is `chat.msg.value` coming from? Sure you've got data there? I'm not sure `chat.msg` will get auto-populated when the elements have that as name only. Better use id (and even better do an explicit select to get the msg element and it's value)

Comment: I looked at your repo, but it seems that you're missing the file that should actually handle the request..

Comment: @Koen it's there: https://github.com/CristoferPortela/chatbox/blob/master/chat/ajx.php

Comment: Ah, you pushed after I looked I guess. But like @DanO 's comment; what do you see in the browser development console?

Comment: Nothing is showing in the browser console, the chat.msg is a form, I checked it,

Comment: I'd recommend changing `+msg` to `+encodeURIComponent(msg)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: oh, yeah, I forgot that, thanks again man

Comment: but I want to make it be send by post method, the get was just for I undertand better how ajax works

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code to the one below and its working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    
    <div>
        <input id="msg">
        <button id="send-mes">Send</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    
<script>
    let send = document.querySelector('#send-mes');
    send.addEventListener('click', load);

    function load() {
        let msg = document.querySelector('#msg').value;
        let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let content = document.querySelector('#content');
                content.innerHTML = this.response;
            }
        }
        xml.open('GET', 'ajx.php?msg='+msg, true);
        xml.send();
    }
</script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but the message appear in the screen and immediately disappear

Comment: @CristoferPortela cancel the button click. `function load(e) {  e.preventDefault();`